# antlr4 grammar non greedy

Tags: python, antlr4

I'm trying to write a grammar the allows me to write any expression in a if statement.

My if statement will be something like below:
if [ x == 1 ] [Do some stuff]

The expression is supposed to be any Python expression.

If I use the non-greedy match like below, how can I specify '[' or ']' as a part of expression? List comprehension will be problem with my grammar.

```
ifval
  : (SPACE)* IF (SPACE|WORD)* SQRLBRACE .*? SQRRBRACE (WORD|SPACE)* <blah> <blah>;

WORD     : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'| '_' | '-')+;
NUM      : [0-9];
NEWLINE  : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
SPACE    : (' ' | '\t') ;
SQRRBRACE: ']';
SQRLBRACE: '[';
```

Comment: I don't understand. You seem to be targeting Python yet if statements in that language do not use square brackets in that way.

Comment: I'm writing a small language that allows me to write some english like statements and converts the 'english like' statements to Python. To evaluate  expressions I had to add an if statement to the language. In the if statement I was hoping to support any pythonic expression. I hope I make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generalized, use a typical statement formulation:

```
stmt   : ifval
       | ....
       ;

ifval  : IF expr body ;

expr   : LBRACK expr? RBRACK
       | NOT expr 
       | WORD ( LBRACK WORD? RBRACK )? // value or array[idx]
       | ....
       ;

body   : WORD
       | LBRACE stmt* RBRACE
       | .... 
       ;
```

The `expr` rule will handle the occurrence of optional and nested brackets through recursion.

BTW, almost always better to hide whitespace in the grammar, even for Python/whitespace sensitive languages. By hiding, the WS remains easily accessible for computing indentation level. And, the grammar is not then polluted by having to specify every conceivable location of SPACE*.